# WPF : How to get mouse position in Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) event

Tags: wpf, mouse-position

WPF : How to get mouse position in Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) event

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this))` ?

(in the `System.Windows.Input` namespace)

Comment: Yes,I have tried GetPosition(Element). It's have to use input element as parameter,isn't it?. I want to get mouse coordinate after click a button on wpf application and show a dialog over the mouse position

Comment: After testing it a bit more it seems it doesn't really matter which element is passed as the parameter.
If your using it on a button_click handler you can call it as `PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(sender as Button))`. The results are absolute, no relative to the control.